# When I attempting to install scipy on windows,the console show that Failed building wheel for scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, pip, intel-mkl

In the cmd, I put the following code :

```
pip install scipy
```

But it doesn't work, and the console show that:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these pre-compiled modules at your own risk http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

EDIT: First image tells it all: you need to provide additional recourses to compile scipy

Comment: Then i download the package "numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl " and run "python numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl install",the console show numpy installed success,but when i try pip install scipy ,it comes to the same situation.

Comment: I mean, install scipy from there as well